# Iterating through a JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-5

Having trouble accessing objects. They are printing as undefined. Help!  I need the code to print the student names.

```
let students = [
        {name: 'Remy', cohort: 'Jan'},
        {name: 'Genevieve', cohort: 'March'},
        {name: 'Chuck', cohort: 'Jan'},
        {name: 'Osmund', cohort: 'June'},
        {name: 'Nikki', cohort: 'June'},
        {name: 'Boris', cohort: 'June'}
    ];



    function objPrint() {
        for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++) {
           console.log("Name: " + students[i][0] + " Cohort: " + students[i][1])
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried forEach? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp

Comment: Well, `students[i]` is not an array, `students[i]` is an object containing `name` and `cohort` properties. So instead of doing `students[i][0]`, you want to do `students[i].name`.

Comment: Thanks everyone! All your answers were great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
let students = [
    {name: 'Remy', cohort: 'Jan'},
    {name: 'Genevieve', cohort: 'March'},
    {name: 'Chuck', cohort: 'Jan'},
    {name: 'Osmund', cohort: 'June'},
    {name: 'Nikki', cohort: 'June'},
    {name: 'Boris', cohort: 'June'}
];



function objPrint() {
    for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++) {
       // Can also use students[i]['name'] , students[i]['cohort']
       // using lodash.js _.get(students, [i, 'name'], 'default value');
       // using new destructuring let {name, cohort} = students[i] then console.log("name: "+ name + " Cohort: "+cohort);
       console.log("Name: " + students[i].name + " Cohort: " + students[i].cohort);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are accessing the items as if it is an array. But in reality is it an array of objects.

The top level, already gets the item that is the current item, just access the keys with dot or bracket notation to get the value.

```js
let students = [
        {name: 'Remy', cohort: 'Jan'},
        {name: 'Genevieve', cohort: 'March'},
        {name: 'Chuck', cohort: 'Jan'},
        {name: 'Osmund', cohort: 'June'},
        {name: 'Nikki', cohort: 'June'},
        {name: 'Boris', cohort: 'June'}
    ];
    
    students.forEach((item) => {
       //console.log(`Name - ${item.name} :: Cohort - ${item.cohort}`);
       console.log('Name - ' + item.name + " :: Cohort - " + item.cohort );
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the key/attribute like this : `students[i].name` and then the method `objPrint()` to print the values.

```js
let students = [
        {name: 'Remy', cohort: 'Jan'},
        {name: 'Genevieve', cohort: 'March'},
        {name: 'Chuck', cohort: 'Jan'},
        {name: 'Osmund', cohort: 'June'},
        {name: 'Nikki', cohort: 'June'},
        {name: 'Boris', cohort: 'June'}
    ];



    function objPrint() {
        for (var i=0; i<students.length; i++) {
           console.log("Name: " + students[i].name + " Cohort: " + students[i].cohort)
        }
    }
    
    objPrint();
```

Answer (score 0):

Properties of objects are access by the dot notation rather than a bracket with number.
So you should do it like this

```
students[i].name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try for..of:

```js
let students = [
    {name: 'Remy', cohort: 'Jan'},
    {name: 'Genevieve', cohort: 'March'},
    {name: 'Chuck', cohort: 'Jan'},
    {name: 'Osmund', cohort: 'June'},
    {name: 'Nikki', cohort: 'June'},
    {name: 'Boris', cohort: 'June'}
]
// returns an object as a student
for(let student of students) {
 console.log(`Name: ${student.name} Cohort: ${student.cohort}`)
}
```

therefore u have access to object's attributes and u can do whatever.

benefits of this approach

- unlike `.foreach()` it works with break, continue, and return
- it avoids all the pitfalls of for–in (working with indexes and not objects)

and also.. use backticks to avoid the old fashioned way of string concatenation - it looks better :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let students = [
        {name: 'Remy', cohort: 'Jan'},
        {name: 'Genevieve', cohort: 'March'},
        {name: 'Chuck', cohort: 'Jan'},
        {name: 'Osmund', cohort: 'June'},
        {name: 'Nikki', cohort: 'June'},
        {name: 'Boris', cohort: 'June'}
    ];

function sobjPrint() {
  for (var i in students) {

    if (students.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
       console.log("Name: " + students[i].name + " Cohort: " + students[i].cohort)
    }
  }
}
```